# PHPUnit warning : Class NodeModelExtensionsTest cannot be found, but it is a trait not a class

Tags: php, class, phpunit, traits

I am getting the following error in PhpUnit:

> Class NodeModelExtensionsTest cannot be found in
> /home/runner/work/baum/baum/tests/Main/Concerns/NodeModelExtensionsTest.php

Odd thing is that NodeModelExtensionsTest is a trait not a class in NodeModelExtensionsTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Baum\Tests\Main\Concerns;

use Baum\Tests\Main\Models\Category;
use Baum\Tests\Main\Models\MultiScopedCategory;
use Baum\Tests\Main\Models\OrderedCategory;
use Baum\Tests\Main\Models\ScopedCategory;
use Baum\Tests\Main\Models\SoftCategory;
use Baum\Tests\Main\Support\PopulateData;

trait NodeModelExtensionsTest
{
  //Rest of the code below...
```

What could be causing this issue and how can it be fixed?

More details:

> PHPUnit 10.0.7
>
> Runtime: PHP 8.1.15

This is for an open source project. Error can be found here: [github actions failed test](https://github.com/TopOnePercent/baum/actions/runs/4192673288/jobs/7268591623)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the trait from `NodeModelExtensionsTest` to `NodeModelExtensionsTestTrait`.

Starting with PHPUnit 10, files in your configured test directory that end with a configured suffix (see `testsuites>testsuite>directory`) in `phpunit.xml` must be classes extending `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`.

I couldn't find an explanation for why it was changed unfortunately. A related issue on GitHub for some context:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4979.